# Xenix TCP/IP Settings for Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, network-interface

[image: issues]

Hello fellow Unix Stack Exchange members

Can you please help I can not figure out the Virtual Box settings for Xenix as it is not DHCP based.

I have Xenix installed with the TCP/IP stack. I have also configured it so far as to have the ability to ping the loopback. I have also learned out how to assign a default gateway so I set it as my router, however I cannot ping 8.8.8.8 or the router 192.168.1.1, I can ping loopback 127.0.0.1.

Virtalbox is set to bridge mode as Xenix cannot use DHCP to my knowledge. Within bridge mode I set the ip address inside of mkdev tcp to a static address. I have this mac address ready inside the router with the static ip. However, it is a no go. I have also tried to use the same IP address as the host Windows 11 machine that was also a no go.

Can you help direct me on how to get this working so I can use lynx browser and see if I can access Google with a Xenix VM? TCP is working to my knowledge because I can ping the loopback address.

Any ideas?

[image: Xenix]

1-27-23 update: I just did some research and noticed that VirtualBox does have the 3com adapter Xenix needs. It is specific for use with 80s operating systems like Xenix, again how can I get access to this option? When I worked as a benchtech years ago I use to see the older ISA adapters all the time.

https://www.virtualbox.org/svn/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Devices/Network/Dev3C501.cpp

[image: virtualbox .cpp file]

Comment: This link does show a 3com and seems to be a vbox expansion file for virtual box. I thought at one time virtualbox had 3com drivers. https://www.virtualbox.org/svn/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Devices/Network/Dev3C501.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you should have better luck with [86Box](https://86box.net/) and [PCap networking](https://86box.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hardware/network.html#pcap). I personally emulate a 3comB (Etherlink II) or WD8013EBT card ([here](https://www.scosales.com/ta/kb/107385.html) you can find which ones are supported by SCO).

The instructions are as follow:

1. install Xenix
2. install the TCP/IP package (and optionally the maintenance update)
3. `mkdev 3comB` (or `mkdev wdn`, depending on your emulated card), to install the driver for the card. Make sure to use the correct IRQ and I/O address. At the next reboot you should be seeing the device (3comB) recognized in the "splash screen", and you should have /dev/3comB0
4. `mkdev tcp` to configure the hostname and IP address of the system. Your broadcast address is likely 192.168.1.255, so don't accept the default one.
5. check that the ifconfig settings in /etc/tcp are in order (see https://virtuallyfun.com/2019/01/15/virtual-xenix-the-internet-pt-2/) and add to it the command for setting your gateway as default route. In your case (as you did) it should be something like `route add default 192.168.1.1 1`
6. create /etc/resolv.conf and add a dns (e.g. `nameserver 8.8.8.8`, with a newline at the end)

Beware that Xenix+TCP/IP is a VERY temperamental combo, and I get every now and then random kernel panics... also, with 3com cards I get poor performance and a lot of "NOTE: tcp sum/src" kernel messages spammed to the console. [The problem is that the driver cannot deal very well with the speed of "modern" systems](https://www.scosales.com/ta/kb/107743.html); we can fix that by emulating a slower machine, or by at least hiding the message. I adapted [SCO's instructions](https://www.scosales.com/ta/kb/107360.html) and did the following to modify the tcpprintfs parameter in the kernel:

```
# cd /
# adb -w xenix -
tcpprintfs/D
[should print _tcpprintfs:  1]
tcpprintfs/W 0
[should print _tcpprintfs:  0x1=    0x0]
$q
# reboot
```

Notice that every time you relink the kernel you need to redo the procedure (or patch the symbol directly in usr/sys/inet/libinet.a, but since it's an archive it takes a few extra steps).